# xpath query not working in https pages?

Tags: php, regex, facebook, xpath, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to extract meta data(open graph tags) of webpages and the following code is working good with all http pages, but as soon as some https link is given it fails.

ex: `https://www.facebook.com/hellocad111`

I checked my server it does supports openssl like this:

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

and the reply was

```
openssl: yes 
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes 
wrappers: array(10) { [0]=> string(5) "https" [1]=> string(4) "ftps" [2]=> string(13) "compress.zlib" [3]=> string(14) "compress.bzip2" [4]=> string(3) "php" [5]=> string(4) "file" [6]=> string(4) "data" [7]=> string(4) "http" [8]=> string(3) "ftp" [9]=> string(3) "zip" }
```

This is my code:

```
function show($link)
{
    $html=file_get_contents($link);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = '//*/meta[starts-with(@property, \'og:\')]';
    $metas = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach ($metas as $meta)
    {
       $property = $meta->getAttribute('property');
       $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
       $rmetas[$property] = $content;
    }
    return $rmetas;
    }
```

and I am getting nothing..

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$html` is the same with HTTP as with HTTPS?

Comment: yes..they are same @RandomSeed

Comment: Have you actually checked `$html`? When I do – no difference between HTTP and HTTPS –, facebook shows an error about the browser being unsupported. Anyway, don't parse Facebook without very good reason, they're providing an API and require signing in for lots of stuff anyway.

Comment: @JensErat  i looked at it and the `$html` is different.But is there any other way without using api.

Comment: Why not use the API? It offers stable, robust and fast access as well as easy-to-use libraries for most languages... Website frontend code changes fast, often and unnoticed, parsing Facebook is doomed to break often and hard. And in the end, _you're not even allowed to_ (when not using the API, read their TOS).

Comment: @JensErat Even if i use API for fb.But still i am not able to parse others like stumbleupon.com

Answer (score 0):

Hah, Terms of Service...
All that means is that they won't give you support unless you're using the API first; you're "*allowed*" to do whatever you want.
However on this one I'm inclined to agree with @Jens; just use the API already. I've been running into similar problems trying to scrape sites *without* APIs, and it's just not possible on a large scale. However, Facebook has been kind enough to offer a friendly API, so don't look a gift horse in the mouth. (whatever *that* means...)